# If $f(A)$ is dense then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let $f\colon A\to R$ be a monotone function and $f(A)$ is dense in some interval $I$ then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Are there any other assumptions?

Comment: no and I can not think of anything

Comment: The statement as it is written is incomplete: what is $A$?

Comment: I can prove it is true if you ask that $I$ contains $f(A)$, I think that was the intended question, I can answer if you post in another question.

Comment: @Jack given the word "monotone" I am pretty sure $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: you want to say the closure of $f(A)$ is an interval ? right? This is the right statement .

Comment: That's nice.  So what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=[0,1]$ and let $f(x)=x$ if $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=x+1$ if $x>\frac{1}{2}$.

Clearly $f$ is not continuous, but $f(A)$ contains $[0,1/2]$ and hence is dense in $[0,1/2]$.

---

If we ask that $f(A)\subseteq I$ then it is true, perhaps that is what is meant:

Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $a\in A$, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)\neq \lim\limits_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ (it is easy to prove both limits exists by using the sequential continuity test and the fact that bounded monotone sequences converge).

It follows that $(\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x), \lim\limits_{x\to a^-}f(x))\cap f(A)=\varnothing$ and so $f(A)$ is not dense in $I$ (because $I$ clearly contains this open interval). (note that in the case in which $f$ is decreasing you need the reversed interval, I did the increasing case).

Comment: I think there must be an error in the statement, I will tell the teacher.

Thanks for your help

Comment: sure no problem.

Comment: Is it fair to say $f(A)$ is dense in $[0, 1/2]$ when $f(A)$ is not contained in $[0, 1/2]$?

Comment: good point, I'll add the other interpretation.